# Is it possible to use @media queries with my JavaScript animated sliding door

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What I would like to achieve is to adjust the width of my sliding door based on the width of the device it is being watched on. From a min-width of 1024px, I would like the width of my sliding door (when it is open) to be 33% of the width of the screen. When the width of the screen is less than 1024px, I would like my door to have a fixed width of 350px, like it is right now.

Does someone know if this is possible? without having to change my complete code?

Here is a fiddle:

```js
$("#left-door").click(function(){
  if ( $(this).hasClass("isOpen") ) {
    $(this).animate({
      right: '-300px'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      right: '0'
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("isOpen");
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,html {
    height: 100%;
}


.container {
  position: relative;

  background-color: grey;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 50px;
}

.sliding-panel {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#left-door {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: pink;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  top:0;
  right:-300px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p1{
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: right;
  position: absolute;
top: 45%;
right:-20px;
}

#left-door p2{
  color: black;
  margin-left: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  position:absolute;
top: 10px;
right: -20px;
width: 273px;
line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>[your title here]</title>

  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">

      <div id="left-door" class="sliding-panel">
        <p1>CV • CONTACT</p1>
        <p2>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      Hi! My name is Sacha<br>
      
      </p2>
      </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you want to show that line hi my name is sacha in all window size/screen resoultion?

Comment: Hi @Leothelion, this is just a placeholder text, it will show a different text. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's possible.

just add this style at the last of your CSS file.
If you feel there is not proper animation then you can improve your structure like this [here](https://codepen.io/Femil_32/pen/VwbepmK)

```js
$("#left-door").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("isOpen")) {
    $(this).animate({
      right: '-300px'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).animate({
      right: '0'
    });
  }
  $(this).toggleClass("isOpen");
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.sliding-panel {
  position: fixed;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

#left-door {
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-color: pink;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  top: 0;
  right: -300px;
  width: 350px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

p1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: -45px;
}

#left-door p2 {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  width: 273px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

@media(min-width:1024px) {
  #left-door.isOpen {
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div id="left-door" class="sliding-panel">
      <p1>CV • CONTACT</p1>
      <p2>
        Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br>        Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br>        Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br> Hi! My name is Sacha<br>

      </p2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not work since my JS also includes the width of the sliding door. So when I open the door it works, but when I close it, it does not close completely

Comment: @sachava understood, add right as per your need in this class in media queries

Comment: but I cant put javascript into my @media in css right? I am confused.